# How can I forward a copy of all passing mail in Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: exchange

I'm writing an yet another mail archiving software. It has an SMTP-listener. External MTA should forward (both incoming and outgoing) mail to it.

It was very easy to setup forwarding in postfix through transport maps, there are also bcc maps and probably other options.

But it is not so good with MS Exchange. Admins have used Journalling + Send Connector. But I receive messages wrapped into attachments (doublechecked them with Thunderbird). I'm not Exchange admin, tried to google - haven't found any reasonable options of "Send Connectors".

Asked chatgpt - it suggested another way to forward: mail flow - Create a new rule and so on.

So, the questions are: What method is best to forward large amounts of transit mail in Exchange (I intentionally do not specify version. It should be universal). And is it possible to get original messages, as postfix does?

p.s. I've found a TNEF option, but it seems like some other case, I'm NOT getting **winmail.dat** attaches.

Comment: the best way to do it is not trying to beat the game ;) hornet security for example will be the first mx and afterwards it forward to the original mx

Answer (score 2):

As for getting original messages like postfix does, you can use the new Exchange admin center (EAC) to configure email forwarding. You can [set up email forwarding to a single internal recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/configure-email-forwarding), a single external recipient (using a mail contact), or multiple recipients (using a distribution group)